# Is $\lnot [p\implies q]$ equivalent to $p\implies \lnot q]$?

Tags: logic

I am having trouble with this, I know that $\lnot [p\implies q]$ is equivalent to $\lnot [\lnot p \lor q]$, but is it also equivalent to   $p\implies \lnot q$ ? I did a truth table and found there are an equal amount of truths in both statements. Please help me understand

Comment: No. $P\implies \neg Q$ is equivalent to $\neg P\vee \neg Q=\neg(P\wedge Q)$.

Comment: Just intuitively, these two statements should not be equivalent. Even though $p$ might not imply $q$, it might be the case that $p$ and $r$ imply $q$. This would contradict $p$ implying $\neg q$. I'd check the truth table again.

Comment: If $p$ is False, then any statement of the form "$p\implies whatever$" is True, in which case the first statement is False while the second is True.

Comment: Thank you @BarryCipra !!

Comment: Another way to check it would be to write the truth tables for your two formulas.